# Retrieving latest comments from FQL comment table

Tags: comments, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get the latest replies from the FQL comment table.

My current query is:

```
"SELECT time, comments FROM comment WHERE object_id = X"
```

.. and I can do something like this if I want the latest parent comment since SECS seconds ago:

```
"SELECT time, comments FROM comment WHERE object_id = X AND time > SECS"
```

.. but I want to look into the replies themselves that are in 'comments' column.

```
"SELECT object_id, text, time, comments FROM comment WHERE object_id = X and comments.create_time > SECS"
```

Any ideas? Is there a FQL table where the replies in 'comments" exist?

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve latest replies try this

```
SELECT text, time, id, likes, fromid, comments FROM comment WHERE   is_private = 0 AND 
object_id in (select post_fbid from comment where object_id in (select comments_fbid from   link_stat where url ='YOUR_URL')) 
ORDER BY time DESC limit 0,10
```

To retrieve both comments and replies try this:

```
SELECT text, time, id, likes, fromid, comments FROM comment WHERE   is_private = 0 AND 
object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url ='YOUR_URL') 
or
object_id in (select post_fbid from comment where object_id in (select comments_fbid from   link_stat where url ='YOUR_URL')) 
ORDER BY time DESC limit 0,10
```

*UPDATE*: the comments field has been remove from table comment.